# How to tell if Platform Cache is available in package?

Tags: licenses, subscriber, platform-cache

If I include a Cache Partition in my managed package but don't activate it in the subscriber org (i.e. subscriber has not purchased a license), how do I check if I should be hitting the cache or not? I don't want to spend time hitting the cache unnecessarily.

If I understand the documentation correctly in the absence of a license the capacity of the packaged Partition drops to zero in the subscriber org. It was this premise that prompted me to ask this question.